# Convertendo dados em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se posso fazer o que é explicado no código abaixo.. :

```js
isString = 'nomeUsuario=Bruno'; // String 
toArray = isString.split('='); // Retira o = da String e converte toArray para Array ["nomeUsuario", "Bruno"]
console.log(toArray); // Exibe Array ["nomeUsuario", "Bruno"]
console.log(toArray[0]); // Exibe o nomeUsuario
console.log(toArray[1]); // Exibe o Bruno
/** 
  * Queria saber se posso usar o nomeUsuraio (toArray[0]) 
  * para receber o valor de Bruno (toArray[1]) como o JavaScript
  * faz com uma variável --- exemplo: var nomeUsuario = 'Bruno', ...
  * console.log(nomeUsuario); // imprime Bruno ..
 **/
```

Comment: Acredito que você esteja trabalhando com uma url, não?

Comment: não, só queria saber se posso fazer algo como explicado acima...

Comment: Bom, nesse caso você pode usar `window[toArray[0]] = toArray[1]; console.log(nomeUsuario); `

Comment: Ou seja, vc quer implementar reflexão em JS?

Comment: ajudou, eu ainda estou conhecendo o javascript.

Comment: Detalhe que usar `window` nem sempre é uma boa escolha, se você estiver trabalhando com múltiplos escopos por exemplo. Usando `window` você cria uma variável no escopo global, que pode influenciar em outros códigos js no seu sistema

Comment: Existe outra forma de conseguir exibir esse resultado?

Comment: Cria uma variavel vazia e atribui nela, daria certo não? Da mesma forma que estaria fazendo com a `window`, `variavelQualquer[toArray[0]]`

Comment: Mais facil seria mostrar de que forma você quer usar esse resultado, ou o que vai fazer com ele, pois certamente terá outras formas melhores de fazer o que pretende. No caso citado `console.log(toArray[0]);` dá o resultado que pretende, porque precisa de definir a variavel `nomeUsuario` ?

Comment: isso depende de onde eu retirei o string, certamente existe outras possibilidades de definir um valor para nomeUsuario, mas não é o caso..

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você quer não seria com um array propriamente dito, porém sim com um objeto... por exemplo você poderia fazer.:

```
var objeto = { nomeUsuario: 'Bruno'} //Atribui Bruno para a a propriedade nomeUsuario 
console.log(objeto.nomeUsuario); //Imprimirá Bruno
```

Comment: não é isso - já ta resolvido, se você analisar o código você vê o que eu queria fazer, a solução está nos comentários da pergunta.. valeu!

Comment: ah massa... vlw !!